# Can I ground a digital pin on an Arduino to provide input?

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, ground

I want to monitor whether a fan is turned on or off.  No RPM, no voltage levels... simply just is it on or off.  The fan is 12V and is controlled by a relay.  The relay is closed when a thermocoupler reaches a certain temperature and grounds the internal coil, closing the contacts and providing power to the fan.

I was going to go through the hassle (actually I already did, just haven't installed it yet) of building a small circuit to convert the 12V down to 5V.  Then I had a thought... what if I use the internal pull-up pin on the Arduino to set it "HIGH", and when the thermocoupler grounds, let that ground pull the Arduino pin "LOW," signaling that the fan is on?

I expect I will need to put some sort of safety measure inbetween the Arduino and the thermocoupler to guard against over-drawing the Arduino... but that should work right?

EDIT:  A "proper" schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsEqbc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is exactly how we signal `0` on the pulled-up digital inputs...

Comment: 1) you should draw a **schematic** of the proposed solution, that avoids any misunderstandings. 2) As long as there is **no** other connection to the switch, i.e. it is a separate switch, you can do as you propose. However is the switch is used for something else as well then there must be some form of protection, as minimum protection use a 10 kohm  series resistor to the input. That prevents any damaging currents from flowing.

Comment: You need to make sure you don't pull the input pin higher than its maximum voltage range.

Comment: Is it possible for Arduino to be powered **off** while the fan (and its relay) are operating? You must be careful not to provide a current path from relay-to-Arduino for this case, else the Arduino could do very strange things upon its power-up.

Comment: @glen_geek Each has its own relay, and the relays are powered (12v+) via the same switch.  The Arduino relay is grounded all the time, while the fan relay is grounded only when the temperature is reached.  If anything, the Arduino will be on without the fan on, which should be okay.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie There is NOTHING else connected to this digital pin, and the relay only switches the fan.  I'd post a crude drawing I made... if I knew how.

Comment: If you would like to pull a programmable digital IO line to low, then you really should include a current limiting series resistor to ground.  The resistor should be sized so that if the pin **is mistakenly** set to output mode, the short to ground doesn't destroy your Arduino.  The resistor should also be low-valued enough so that it can still reliably pull the signal well-below the Vin-low voltage threshold when taking into consideration the value of the internal pull-up.  This simple addition will save your precious micro-controller someday, and yer butt.

Comment: *I'd post a crude drawing I made... if I knew how* **Edit** your question and use the schematic drawing function (one of the icons) to draw a schematic. The drawing you included is not a schematic it is a block diagram and not so useful as it shows no real components. See Trevor's answer for a **proper** schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple diode to the relay should work for you if you use the pull-up on the Arduino input. The diode prevents the fan power from driving into the pull-up. If you are using a 3.3V Arduino you may need to use a germanium diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foZ2gU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A small series resistor would not hurt too just in case you happen to drive the pin with the relay closed.

Comment: It looks like you are suggesting driving the pin from the positive side of the relay?  Or are you using a relay to represent the thermocoupler?  I was planning to run from the ground to pull the pin low... with current limiting resistor of course.

Comment: *positive side of the relay?* Relay contacts do not have a positive or negative side. **If** there was a positive voltage on the upper (in the schematic) contact then the diode would block any current flow.

Comment: Looks good, but a critical item is missing from this schematic - the Arduino **must** have a common-ground with the relay for this to work. It might be wise to show a more complete 5v supply for the Arduino. If the common-ground is forbidden, then so is this solution.

Comment: @glen_geek I thought by powering the Arduino through the 12V plug (not USB) that there was a common ground?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  I am an accountant with too much time on my hands :)  When I say "positive side of the relay," what I mean is the side that is attached to the switch as opposed to the side that is attached to ground (through the thermocoupler).

Comment: Guys, it's "thermocouple" as in "a couple of wires" - not a "thermocoupler". It doesn't couple heat between two objects.

Comment: @Transistor  How about this... temperature activated switch.

Comment: "Thermostat" is the word I think we're searching for. The thermocouple I mentioned is a two wire temperature sensor.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor. I didn't even think to use the relay to switch ground.  That make it work perfect. And much simpler than what I had

Comment: @jcmeyer5 BTW I'd add one or two more diodes to that circuit. Both pointing up. 1.) from the top of the relay to 12V to take care of the inductor in the motor turning off and make your relay last longer. 2) one across the contacts of the relay. The latter prevents the top of the relay from going negative when the fan is spinning and the power goes off. (Fans act as generators). I am assuming you already have one on the coil side of the relay.